# Missing class: okhttp3.internal.http.UnrepeatableRequestBody

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, okhttp

I updated Android Studio to 3.5 and now I have problem with

```
minifyEnabled true
```

When I try send json data with okhttp3, the body is null.

I tried to add these rules to proguard, but the problem remains.

```
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
```

I see only this warning when minifyEnabled is true and only when I change the version. :-| 
[image]

Any ideas?

For the moment I set minifyEnabled to false. -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`UnrepeatableRequestBody`** has been removed in v3.14 with this PR: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/4676.

So, I ended up ignoring the warning by adding:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.http.UnrepeatableRequestBody
```

Now, why it's warning us about that missing interface? Well, I guess it's because  one of the **okhttp3** internal libraries relied on `UnrepeatableRequestBody` which got removed and it's probably a temporary warning that will be fixed when the internal library gets updated with the `RequestBody#isOneShot` new feature.